# How to get date of birth of facebook user using facebook sdk in android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, date

I am developing an android application,I can fetch Firstname,Lastname,email of user using facebook sdk 4.But I am unable to get date of birth,address.I have tried setting permission to the login button.I don't know is there any configuration missing on Facebook API.

Please help me,
Thanks in advance

```
String permissions[] = { "email","user_birthday","public_profile"};
fbLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
fbLogin.setReadPermissions(permissions);

@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken(); 
accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
Profile pf=Profile.getCurrentProfile();
Log.e("Permissions...", ""+AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions());   

//AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getDeclinedPermissions();
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            String email;
            String firstName;
            String lastName;
            String gender;
            String country;
            String dob, name, picPath, id;

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
                    GraphResponse response) {

                try {

                    id = object.getString("id");                        
                    name = object.getString("name");
                    firstName = object.getString("first_name");
                    lastName = object.getString("last_name");
                    gender = object.getString("gender");
                    country = object.getString("address");
                    picPath = Utility.getFbProfileurl(id);
                    Log.e(" birthday..", "..."+object.getString("user_birthday"));
                    dob = object.getString("user_birthday");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters
        .putString("fields",
                "name,email,address,first_name,last_name,gender,location,birthday,locale");

request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();

}
```

Comment: Just answered it 2 days earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475977/unable-to-get-fb-user-birthday-android/32476330#32476330

Comment: I have read this from facbook documentation.But not helping this,  "there is an age_range field included in the public profile for anyone who installs your app. This field may be sufficient for your app instead of requesting user_birthday permission."