# Facebook's Graph Request returning null

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have an Android app that allows users to login with Facebook with their Login button. I've set the permission as follow for the loginButton :

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(
             "public_profile","user_birthday","user_location");
```

The login works fine but what i want to do is basically get some additional info about their birthdate and actual location in order to create a new "User" object and write it into my database in this way :

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,first_name,last_name,gender, birthday,link,location");
        final User newUser= new User();

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i("***LoginResponse :",response.toString());

                    try {

                         String userGender = response.getJSONObject().getString("gender");
                         String firstName = response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name");
                         String lastName = response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name");
                         String facebookProfileLink = response.getJSONObject().getString("link");

                         String userBirthdate = response.getJSONObject().getString("birthday");

                        String userCity = response.getJSONObject().getJSONObject("location").getString("name");


                        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                        String id = profile.getId();
                        String link = profile.getLinkUri().toString();
                        Uri profilePicture = profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200);
                        Log.i("Link",link);


                        newUser.setUserAge(userBirthdate);
                        Log.i("****Login" + "UserBirthday", userBirthdate);

                        newUser.setUserEmail("default@facebook.com");
                        newUser.setUserGender(genderFixer(userGender));


                        newUser.setUserCity(userCity);
                        Log.i("****Login" + "UserCity", userCity);

                        newUser.setFacebookProfile(facebookProfileLink);
                        newUser.setUserName(firstName);
                        newUser.setUserSurname(lastName);
                        newUser.setProfileImage(profilePicture.toString());


                        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        mDatabaseReference.child(userId).setValue(newUser);

                        if (Profile.getCurrentProfile()!=null)
                        {
                            Log.i("Login", "ProfilePic" + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(200, 200));
                        }


                        Log.i("****Login"+ "FirstName", firstName);
                        Log.i("****Login" + "LastName", lastName);
                        Log.i("****Login" + "Gender", userGender);



                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
    );
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

I can read all the data but not "birthday" and "location" -> "name".
NOTE : i'm perfectly aware that those fields can be empty and i know how to handle it but i'm testing with an account that actually has those fields on the Facebook profile. This is the response i'm getting :

```
I/***LoginResponse :: {Response:  responseCode: 200, 
   graphObject: {
"id":"116293545526048",           
"first_name":"Davide",
"last_name":"Harlee",
"gender":"male",
"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/116293545526048\/"},          error: null}
```

This only happens on 2 test account i made while logging with my "real" facebook account i get all the information i need without problems getting location and birthday just fine

Comment: I think you should check this out it's something about permission and send it to review if you want to access the birthdate [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32476330/3800164)

Comment: Thanks for the answer i forgot to add an important point on th eoriginal post, editing it

Comment: Before you can ask users that don’t have a role in the app for those permissions, you need to get them reviewed.