# Using Facebook Api birthday return null In android

Tags: android, facebook, user-interface, facebook-graph-api, interface

In Android App Integrated Facebook Api. I am using Facebook sdk:4.21.0,But when GraphRequest Call birthday not return in Json Response. Please let me know whats wrong. I am also tested through give the public permission to date of birth of user.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        LogUtils.logE(TAG, "JsonResponse: " + object);

                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,birthday,picture.type(large)");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32476330/1790537 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/31556390/1790537

Comment: did you add the permission in `loginButton`?

Comment: I am Using following code for login   `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MyProfileActivity.this, Collections.singletonList("email,public_profile,user_friends"));
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()`

Comment: @Nas How can i will get privacy url?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `user_birthday` parameter in your `logInWithReadPermissions()` method

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MyProfil‌​eActivity.this, Collections.singletonList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
```

**OR**

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
```

Comment: Not working `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MyProfileActivity.this, Collections.singletonList("email,public_profile,user_friends,user_birthday"));`

Comment: if the user make their birthday private in facebook...graph api will not return it..

Comment: Yes Sir, But I have tested make user birthday public. but aslo graph api not return.

Comment: i have edited the post..and also clean build the apk. Rather than instant run

Comment: Means what ? Its properly working in Your code? I need to App Send for Review?

Comment: I haven't apply for App Review so need to do it first?